# Which Ubuntu package has the CA for debian.neo4j.org (godaddy)?

Tags: ubuntu, certificate-authority, curl, wget, neo4j

The neo4j site shows that you should get their certificate using

```
wget -q -O - http://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
```

This, of course, could allow their certificate to be hacked. So, I really should use `https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key` instead. But when I do, neither `wget` nor `curl` can find the certificate. On the other hand, Chrome seems perfectly happy with it.

Here's the detailed message from `wget`:

> ERROR: cannot verify debian.neo4j.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Go
>   Daddy Secure Certificate Authority -
>   G2,OU=[http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\](http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com%5C),
>   Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US’:

I have to use a command line tool in this context, and I very strongly prefer to use **https*.  What package will install the certificiate I need?

[I already know about `--no-check-certificate`. That's not what I want]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that website failed to send the required intermediate certificate along, and intermediate certificates are not typically installed. You can check this by running

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect debian.neo4j.org:443
```

Which tells us

```
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.neo4j.org
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.neo4j.org
verify error:num=27:certificate not trusted
verify return:1
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = *.neo4j.org
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.neo4j.org
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
```

So now it's time for some manual steps. As you can see, the web page where GoDaddy makes these certificates available is listed. In this case we'll need

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt
```

So, now we give this certificate to wget, and you'll see that it's happy:

```
wget -q --ca-certificate gdig2.crt -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key
```

Comment: So this is something that godaddy should also correct?

Comment: @AlanRobertson no, neo4j fails to send the proper bundle of certificates to you, so they should correct this. It's probably just an oversight that in most cases won't visible in regular browsers and is thus easily missed during testing. Godaddy, the certificate provider, can't do anything about this situation.

Comment: @fvu you were bang on.  I didn't install the full certificate chain.  Fixed now.